# How to export Hyper-V VM remotely

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will allow users to export a VM from a Hyper-V host to a network share without allowing users access to the Hyper-V host server.  The script would be run from a 2008/2012 R2 server or perhaps a windows workstation, against a 2012 R2 Hyper-V host that will export a VM off to a share on another 2012 R2 server.  Exporting to the host itself first is not an option due to lack of available disk space.

From the host server, running powershell as administrator, I am able to successfully run the export command: *Export-VM -Name My_VM -Path "\Server\Share"*  and everything 'just works.'

​However trying to run this from a script or shell on another server with Invoke-Command or a PSSession​ results in "Failed to create export directory with error 'General access denied error '(0x80070005)..." 
All the solutions I've found so far are only applicable to running the command directly from the host, not remotely.

Has anyone been able to remotely export a Hyper-V VM to a network share?

Comment: Sounds like the [Second Hop Problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/) to me.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/matthts/2012/06/10/configuring-kerberos-constrained-delegation-for-hyper-v-management/

Comment: Thanks, looks promising.  I'll let you know when I've had a chance to test this out!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the link Ansgar, [second hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/matthts/2012/06/10/configuring-kerberos-constrained-delegation-for-hyper-v-management/) = second hop solution!

From a 2012 R2 server I was able to run the following in powershell:

```
Set-ADComputer -Identity $FileShareServer -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount $HVHost1,$HVHost2,$HVHost...,
```

Verified settings with:

```
$x = Get-ADComputer -Identity $FileShareServer -Properties msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity
$x.'msDS-AllowedToActOnBehalfOfOtherIdentity'.Access
```

Successfully tested on "jump server" running invoke-command against HV host to export VM to network share.

Much appreciated!

Comment: FYI, I found that when you reference your network share, you **must** use the ActiveDirectory machine name or DNS name. If you use any other DNS name, or an IP address, the command will fail. E.g. You're on HostA and you want to export the VM named VM1, that's running on HvHost, to a share on FileShareHost:  `Export-VM -ComputerName HvHost -Name VM1 -Path "\\FileShareHost\share" `  If FileShareHost is also accessible (from any host involved in this example) by file1.internal.local and you use that instead, the export will fail (the 0x80070005 one).